# Table already exists,but it doesn't

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to implement a many to many relationship inorder to implement an authorisation module.As symfony suggests, i am tryng to mmake two tables user and roles with many to many realtionship. I already wrote a metadata file and i am tryng to generate database schema using this.

Following is my metadata files.

VmsUsers.orm .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
<entity name="Office\DigitxpBundle\Entity\VmsUsers" table="vms_users" >

<id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
  <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
</id>
<field name="username" type="string" column="username" length="20" nullable="false"/>
<field name="salt" type="string" column="salt" length="20" nullable="true"/>
<field name="password" type="string" column="password" length="20" nullable="false"/>
<field name="email" type="string" column="email" length="20" nullable="false"/>
<field name="isActive" type="boolean" column="is_active" nullable="false"/>
<many-to-many field="userRoles" target-entity="Role">
            <cascade>
                <cascade-all/>
            </cascade>
            <join-table name="user_role">
                <join-columns>
                    <join-column name="roles" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="false" unique="false" />
                </join-columns>
                <inverse-join-columns>
                    <join-column name="user" referenced-column-name="id" column-definition="INT NULL" />
                </inverse-join-columns>
            </join-table>
    </many-to-many>
 </entity>
 </doctrine-mapping>
```

When i try to run

```
  doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I got like

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]           
  The table with name 'vms1.role' already exists.
```

But my database does not have a role table. I dont know whats causing this error?Any idea how to fix this?Many thanks in advance.

Comment: what database are you using? some db engines have a few built-in hidden tables

Comment: MySql..i am working on xampp with PhpMyAdmin

Comment: i created an empty database and tried! still no way!

Comment: A many to many relation uses a join table to track the relationships. Your schema is trying to create a join table with same name as your normal table.

Also in your join tables you also have 2 ID fields...

Comment: @SparK..can u please explain your point?

Comment: TableA has a many to many relationship to TableB. Then the join table must be called something like "TableA_TableB" where you have the Ids of each table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you will need to change this line:

```
<join-table name="role">
```

to

```
<join-table name="users2role">
```

This is a join table - third table in the relation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename to `roles`:

```
<entity name="Office\DigitxpBundle\Entity\Role" table="roles">
```